# What's wrong with the Newton-Leibniz formula?

Tags: integration

What's wrong with the Newton-Leibniz formula? $\int_0^\frac{3\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx
=\arctan(\sec x)|_0^\frac{3\pi}{4}
=-\arctan \sqrt{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$. This gives a wrong answer. Where goes wrong?

Comment: Your antiderivative is wrong. -$\arctan(\cos x)$ is the correct one.

Comment: @FDP The OP's answer also works; differentiate it.

Comment: @JG:  $\frac{3\pi}{4}>\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sec x$ doesn't exist for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\frac{3\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx
=-\arctan(\cos x)|_0^\frac{3\pi}{4}
=-\arctan  (-\sqrt{2}/2 )+\frac{\pi}{4} =\arctan  (\sqrt{2}/2 )+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\arctan\sec x$ has a discontinuity at $x=\pi/2$, because $\sec x$ becomes $\infty$ from below and $-\infty$ from above, and its arctangent changes discontinuously from just under $\pi/2$ to just over $-\pi/2$. If you split the integral at $x=\pi/2$, then add the two integrals together, it'll work out.